# Handle states dynamically for multiple inputboxes

Tags: reactjs, date, state

I have a component where I select a start and end date and a start and end time for a session. I have code so that I can add another date and time range for the session when I press "Add more date range".

What I'm struggling with is adding states correctly, basically I obviously want to have one individual state per "dateRange selection box", but I'm not sure how to acheive that. Currently the state is the same for each item, so if I select 10th to 11th of May, it will be like that in all input boxes.

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { DateRange } from "react-date-range";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main style file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { notifyAction } from "../../redux/actions/notificationAction";
import api from "../../services/api";
import * as types from "../../types/types";
import Select from "react-select";
import lineIcon from "../../public/assests/icon/LineIcon.svg";
import Image from "next/image";
import ClockIcon from "../../public/assests/icon/clockIcon.svg";
import CalenderIcon from "../../public/assests/icon/CalenderIcon.svg";

interface props {
  isPopupOpen: boolean;
  setIsPopupOpen: any;
  sessionId: number;
  sessionTitle: string;
  name: string;
  closeUpAction: any;
  isOpenFromForm: boolean;
}
const StartHours = [
  { value: "00:00", label: "00:00 AM" },
  { value: "01:00", label: "01:00 AM" },
  { value: "02:00", label: "02:00 AM" },
  { value: "03:00", label: "03:00 AM" },
  { value: "04:00", label: "04:00 AM" },
  { value: "05:00", label: "05:00 AM" },
  { value: "06:00", label: "06:00 AM" },
  { value: "07:00", label: "07:00 AM" },
  { value: "08:00", label: "08:00 AM" },
  { value: "09:00", label: "09:00 AM" },
  { value: "10:00", label: "10:00 AM" },
  { value: "11:00", label: "11:00 AM" },
  { value: "12:00", label: "12:00 AM" },
  { value: "13:00", label: "13:00 PM" },
  { value: "14:00", label: "14:00 PM" },
  { value: "15:00", label: "15:00 PM" },
  { value: "16:00", label: "16:00 PM" },
  { value: "17:00", label: "17:00 PM" },
  { value: "18:00", label: "18:00 PM" },
  { value: "19:00", label: "19:00 PM" },
  { value: "20:00", label: "20:00 PM" },
  { value: "21:00", label: "21:00 PM" },
  { value: "22:00", label: "22:00 PM" },
  { value: "23:00", label: "23:00 PM" },
];

const SessionPopup = (props: props) => {
  let INITIALDATA = {
    serviceId: props.sessionId,
    startDate: "",
    endDate: "",
    startTime: "",
    endTime: "",
  };

  const [numDateRanges, setNumDateRanges] = useState(1);
  const { isPopupOpen, setIsPopupOpen } = props;
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<any>(INITIALDATA);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [selectedfinishHour, setSelectedfinishHour] = useState<any>(
    StartHours[0]
  );
  const [selectedStartHour, setSelectedStartHour] = useState<any>(
    StartHours[0]
  );
  const [showFinishModel, setShowFinishModel] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showStartModel, setShowStartModel] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleSelect = (ranges: any) => {
    setStartDate(ranges.selection.startDate);
    setEndDate(ranges.selection.endDate);
  };

  const selectionRange = {
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate,
    key: "selection",
  };

  const handleAddDateRangeClick = () => {
    setNumDateRanges(numDateRanges + 1);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    setShowStartModel(false);
    setShowFinishModel(false);
  };
  const formatDate = (date: any) => {
    return date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
      month: "short",
      day: "numeric",
    });
  };
  const style = "#B4B4B4";
  const inputText = `${formatDate(startDate)} - ${formatDate(endDate)}`;
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    if (props.isOpenFromForm) {
      setIsPopupOpen(!isPopupOpen);
      props.closeUpAction();
    } else {
      setIsPopupOpen(!isPopupOpen);
    }
  };
  const dispatch = useDispatch<any>();

  const onChange = useCallback(() => {
    let begin = startDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    let end = endDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    setFormData({
      serviceId: props.sessionId,
      startDate: begin,
      endDate: end,
      startTime: selectedStartHour.value,
      endTime: selectedfinishHour.value,
    });
  }, [
    startDate,
    endDate,
    selectedStartHour,
    selectedfinishHour,
    props.sessionId,
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const memoizedOnChange = () => {
      onChange();
    };

    memoizedOnChange();
  }, [onChange]);
  const handleStartHourSelect = (event: any, hour: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSelectedStartHour(hour);
  };
  const handleFinishHourSelect = (event: any, hour: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSelectedfinishHour(hour);
  };
  const handleInputClickStart = () => {
    setShowStartModel(true);
    setShowFinishModel(false);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };
  const handleInputClickFinish = () => {
    setShowStartModel(false);
    setIsOpen(false);
    setShowFinishModel(true);
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    onChange();
    await api
      .post(`services/session/schedule`, formData)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(
          notifyAction({
            type: types.SUCCESS,
            message: "Session Added Successfully",
          })
        );
        handleButtonClick();
        if (props.isOpenFromForm) {
          props.closeUpAction();
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response!.status === 409)
          dispatch(
            notifyAction({
              type: types.WARNING,
              message:
                error.response?.data!.message! || "Please Fill Required Fields",
            })
          );
        else if (error)
          dispatch(
            notifyAction({
              type: types.WARNING,
              message: "Please Fill Required Fields",
            })
          );
      });
  };
  const closeStartModel = () => {
    setShowStartModel(false);
  };
  const closeEndModel = () => {
    setShowFinishModel(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 md:overflow-y-scroll  z-50 flex justify-center items-center">
        <div className="bg-white h-[90vh] overflow-auto no-scrollbar flex flex-col lg:w-6/12 md:w-full py-4 rounded-xl font-montserrat">
          <div className="flex justify-between border-b-2 p-2 px-4">
            <p className="text-xl text-[#1E1E1E] font-bold">
              Schedule {props.name}
            </p>
            <div>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="text-gray-400 justify-end bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                data-modal-hide="defaultModal"
                onClick={handleButtonClick}
              >
                <svg
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  className="w-5 h-5"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    fillRule="evenodd"
                    d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                    clipRule="evenodd"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
                <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form>
            <div className="px-4 py-2">
              <h2 className="text-lg text-[#1E1E1E] font-bold">
                Type and date
              </h2>
              <div className="flex flex-col mb-2 py-2">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="mb-1 text-base ">
                  {props.name} name
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={props.sessionTitle}
                  className="px-3 py-2 text-base border border-gray-400 rounded-md"
                  placeholder={props.sessionTitle}
                  disabled
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-2">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="mb-1 text-base  font-bold">
                  Choose date and time
                </label>
              </div>
              {Array.from({ length: numDateRanges }, (_, index) => (
                <div className="flex flex-col mb-2" key={index}>
                  {
                    <div className="flex flex-col mb-2">
                      <div className="flex text-[#575757] gap-4 w-full">
                        <div className="relative w-6/12" ref={ref}>
                          <input
                            className="w-full pl-8 py-3 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                            type="text"
                            value={inputText}
                            onClick={handleClick}
                            readOnly
                          />
                          <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-2">
                            <Image
                              src={CalenderIcon}
                              alt=""
                              className="w-[15px]"
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>{" "}
                        <div className="flex items-center">
                          <div className="relative">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              value={selectedStartHour.value}
                              onClick={handleInputClickStart}
                              className="py-3 pl-8 text-xs border border-gray-400 rounded-md w-10/12"
                              onChange={(e) =>
                                setSelectedStartHour(
                                  StartHours.find(
                                    (hour) => hour.value === e.target.value
                                  )
                                )
                              }
                            />
                            <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-2">
                              <Image
                                src={ClockIcon}
                                alt=""
                                className="w-[20px]"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <Image src={lineIcon} alt="line" className="pr-2" />
                          </div>
                          <div className="relative">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              value={selectedfinishHour.value}
                              onClick={handleInputClickFinish}
                              className="py-3 pl-8 text-xs border border-gray-400 rounded-md w-10/12"
                              onChange={(e) =>
                                setSelectedfinishHour(
                                  StartHours.find(
                                    (hour) => hour.value === e.target.value
                                  )
                                )
                              }
                            />
                            <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-2">
                              <Image
                                src={ClockIcon}
                                alt=""
                                className="w-[20px]"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      {isOpen && (
                        <div className="z-10 top-full left-0 mt-2 px-4">
                          <div className="bg-white border rounded-lg shadow-lg w-full sm:w-7/12 ">
                            <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
                              <DateRange
                                editableDateInputs={true}
                                ranges={[selectionRange]}
                                onChange={handleSelect}
                                showDateDisplay={false}
                                showMonthAndYearPickers={false}
                                rangeColors={[style]}
                              />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex border border-t-2 justify-between p-1">
                              <button
                                className="border-2 border-[#1E1E1E] flex items-right font-montserrat font-medium text-[#1E1E1E] text-xs px-4 py-2"
                                onClick={handleClick}
                              >
                                CANCEL
                              </button>
                              <button
                                className="bg-[#5F7474] text-[#FFFFFF] text-xs font-montserrat font-medium px-6 py-2"
                                onClick={handleClick}
                              >
                                APPLY
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                      <div className="flex justify-end">
                        {showStartModel ? (
                          <div className="flex flex-col w-6/12 border rounded-xl h-[300px] border-[#D7D7D7]">
                            <h3 className="font-bold text-sm border-b-2 p-2">
                              Choose starting time
                            </h3>
                            <div className="overflow-y-scroll">
                              {StartHours.map((hour, idx) => (
                                <button
                                  key={idx}
                                  onClick={(event) =>
                                    handleStartHourSelect(event, hour)
                                  }
                                  className="flex p-2"
                                >
                                  {hour.label}
                                </button>
                              ))}
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex border border-t-2 justify-between p-1">
                              <button
                                className="border-2 border-[#1E1E1E] flex items-right font-montserrat font-medium text-[#1E1E1E] text-xs px-4 py-2"
                                onClick={closeStartModel}
                              >
                                CANCEL
                              </button>
                              <button
                                className="bg-[#5F7474] text-[#FFFFFF] text-xs font-montserrat font-medium px-6 py-2"
                                onClick={closeStartModel}
                              >
                                APPLY
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ) : null}
                        {showFinishModel ? (
                          <div className="flex flex-col w-6/12 border rounded-xl h-[300px] border-[#D7D7D7]">
                            <h3 className="font-bold text-sm border-b-2 p-2">
                              Choose Ending time
                            </h3>
                            <div className="overflow-y-scroll">
                              {StartHours.map((hour, idx) => (
                                <button
                                  key={idx}
                                  onClick={(event) =>
                                    handleFinishHourSelect(event, hour)
                                  }
                                  className="flex p-2"
                                >
                                  {hour.label}
                                </button>
                              ))}
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex border border-t-2 justify-between p-1">
                              <button
                                className="border-2 border-[#1E1E1E] flex items-right font-montserrat font-medium text-[#1E1E1E] text-xs px-4 py-2"
                                onClick={closeEndModel}
                              >
                                CANCEL
                              </button>
                              <button
                                className="bg-[#5F7474] text-[#FFFFFF] text-xs font-montserrat font-medium px-6 py-2"
                                onClick={closeEndModel}
                              >
                                APPLY
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  }
                </div>
              ))}
              <button type="button" onClick={handleAddDateRangeClick}>
                Add more date range
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div className="flex justify-end mt-auto border-t-2">
            <button
              className="bg-[#5F7474] text-[#FFFFFF] text-sm font-montserrat font-medium px-6 py-2 m-2"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
            >
              SAVE
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SessionPopup;
```